# How to properly let goroutine finish gracefully when main is interrupted?

Tags: go, go-context

In the following example, when Ctrl+C is pressed, the `work` gorountine finishes gracefully before `main` exits:

```go
package main

import (
    "os"
    "time"
    "os/signal"
    "context"
    "syscall"
    "fmt"
)

func work(ctx context.Context, done chan struct{}) {
    defer close(done)
    fmt.Println("work starting its loop")
    out:
    for {
        select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                fmt.Println("ctx.Done() inside work")
                break out
            default:
                time.Sleep(time.Second)
                fmt.Println("work heartbeat")
        }
    }
    fmt.Println("work finished")
}

func main() {
    interrupt := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(interrupt, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    defer cancel()
    done := make(chan struct{})
    go func() {
        <-interrupt
        cancel()
    }()
    go work(ctx, done)
    <-ctx.Done()
    fmt.Println("ctx.Done() inside main")
    <-done
    fmt.Println("Main finished")
}
```

However, I suspect the code is suboptimal. Is the `done` channel necessary? Shouldn't graceful termination of goroutines be achieved with `context` alone? What if there were many worker goroutines, not just one?

Comment: I don't think so, the main purpose is solved by the context cancellation mechanism. So 'No' the done channel is not really needed

Comment: @Inian I tried without `done`: the `work` function gets terminated abruptly, the "work finished" line is not printed.

Comment: The context doesn’t tell you when the goroutine returns, it is being used to communicate cancellation _to_ the goroutine. A context doesn’t have any sort of two way communication.

Comment: @JimB Good to know. Perhaps, the worker should then detach and finish on its own rather than be terminated when main exits?

Comment: You can’t “detach” a goroutine. It no longer exists once the process exits.

Comment: @JimB Then I don't really get how context is supposed to help with graceful shutdowns.

Comment: A context communicates cancelation down the tree of contexts. It has nothing to do with waiting for graceful shutdowns. The standard way to wait for completion is a [WaitGroup](https://pkg.go.dev/sync#WaitGroup) (but a channel does the same thing in the simple case of a single goroutine)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually it has gotten much simpler with [`signal.NotifyContext`](https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal#NotifyContext): We simply pass a context and get a "ContextWithCancel". Now, if that context is "Done" we received a signal and if we pass the context to all of our goroutines, all goroutines will take note of that and finish.

```golang
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os/signal"
    "sync"
    "syscall"
    "time"
)

func work(ctx context.Context, number int, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    // We use a wait group to ensure that main blocks until the work has finished.
    defer wg.Done()
    fmt.Printf("worker %d starting its loop\n", number)
out:
    for {
        select {
        // We simply reuse the context to check if the work should stop.
        case <-ctx.Done():
            fmt.Println("ctx.Done() inside work")
            break out
        default:
            time.Sleep(time.Second)
            fmt.Printf("work heartbeat from worker %d\n", number)
        }
    }
    fmt.Printf("worker %d finished\n", number)
}

var wg sync.WaitGroup

func main() {
    // No need to use channels here, we can use the context directly.
    ctx, stop := signal.NotifyContext(context.Background(), syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM)
    defer stop()

    for i := 0; i < 3; i++ {
        // Add 1 for each goroutine we start.
        wg.Add(1)
        go work(ctx, i, &wg)
    }

    // We received a signal, cancel the context.
    sig := <-ctx.Done()
    fmt.Printf("Got signal: %v\n", sig)
    fmt.Println("ctx.Done() inside main")

    // We ensure that the work has finished before exiting.
    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println("Main finished")
}
```

Comment: Guess a further optimization would be to use `context.WithValue` to attach `WaitGroup` to it, instead of passing it as a separate argument.

Comment: @Greendrake Guess you are right. ;)