# How to quickly terminate child processes in Go and proceed only when killed

Tags: go, process

I have a Go program that starts a Docker Compose process using exec.CommandContext. I've set up a context with cancellation and a signal handler to cancel the context when an interrupt signal (Ctrl+C) is received. The goal is to terminate the Docker Compose process and all its child processes quickly when the context is canceled.

However, I've noticed that it takes a significant amount of time to close all the child processes after canceling the context. I want to improve the speed at which these processes are terminated.

Here's a simplified version of my code:

```
package main

import (
    "context"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "os/signal"
    "path/filepath"
    "sort"
    "strconv"
    "strings"
    "syscall"

    "go.uber.org/zap"
)

var cancel context.CancelFunc

func main() {
    ctx := NewCtx()
    username := os.Getenv("SUDO_USER")
    fmt.Println("sdgnsaj")
    keployAlias := "docker-compose -f /home/shivamsouravjha.linux/dockerEvent/docker-compose.yml up"

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sh", "-c", keployAlias+" --build")
    if username != "" {
        // print all environment variables
        // Run the command as the user who invoked sudo to preserve the user environment variables and PATH
        cmd = exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sudo", "-E", "-u", os.Getenv("SUDO_USER"), "env", "PATH="+os.Getenv("PATH"), "sh", "-c", "docker-compose up")
    }
    cmd.Cancel = func() error {

        return InterruptProcessTree(cmd, cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGTERM)
    }
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stdin = os.Stdin
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr
    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("errro", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("the pid", cmd.Process.Pid)

    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("asdasdsa")
    }
}

func NewCtx() context.Context {
    // Create a context that can be canceled
    ctx, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())

    SetCancel(cancel)
    // Set up a channel to listen for signals
    sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    // os.Interrupt is more portable than syscall.SIGINT
    // there is no equivalent for syscall.SIGTERM in os.Signal
    signal.Notify(sigs, os.Interrupt, syscall.SIGTERM)

    // Start a goroutine that will cancel the context when a signal is received
    go func() {
        <-sigs
        fmt.Println("Signal received, canceling context...")
        cancel()
    }()

    return ctx
}

func SetCancel(c context.CancelFunc) {
    cancel = c
}

// InterruptProcessTree interrupts an entire process tree using the given signal
func InterruptProcessTree(cmd *exec.Cmd, ppid int, sig syscall.Signal) error {
    // Find all descendant PIDs of the given PID & then signal them.
    // Any shell doesn't signal its children when it receives a signal.
    // Children may have their own process groups, so we need to signal them separately.
    children, err := FindChildPIDs(ppid)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }

    children = append(children, ppid)
    sort.Slice(children, func(i, j int) bool { return children[i] > children[j] })
    for _, pid := range children {
        fmt.Println("this is child pid of parent", pid)
        if cmd.ProcessState == nil {
            err := syscall.Kill(pid, sig)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("failed to send signal to process", zap.Int("pid", pid), zap.Error(err))
            }
            // time.Sleep(250 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }

    return nil
}

// findChildPIDs takes a parent PID and returns a slice of all descendant PIDs.
func FindChildPIDs(parentPID int) ([]int, error) {
    var childPIDs []int

    // Recursive helper function to find all descendants of a given PID.
    var findDescendants func(int)
    findDescendants = func(pid int) {
        procDirs, err := os.ReadDir("/proc")
        if err != nil {
            return
        }

        for _, procDir := range procDirs {
            if !procDir.IsDir() {
                continue
            }

            childPid, err := strconv.Atoi(procDir.Name())
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }

            statusPath := filepath.Join("/proc", procDir.Name(), "status")
            statusBytes, err := os.ReadFile(statusPath)
            if err != nil {
                continue
            }

            status := string(statusBytes)
            for _, line := range strings.Split(status, "\n") {
                if strings.HasPrefix(line, "PPid:") {
                    fields := strings.Fields(line)
                    if len(fields) == 2 {
                        ppid, err := strconv.Atoi(fields[1])
                        if err != nil {
                            break
                        }
                        if ppid == pid {
                            childPIDs = append(childPIDs, childPid)
                            findDescendants(childPid)
                        }
                    }
                    break
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Start the recursion with the initial parent PID.
    findDescendants(parentPID)

    return childPIDs, nil
}
```

this process then calls an image goose which runs similarly:-

```
func main() {

    username := os.Getenv("SUDO_USER")
    ctx := NewCtx()
    fmt.Println("sdgnsaj")
    keployAlias := "docker-compose -f /home/shivamsouravjha.linux/dockerEvent/a/docker-compose.yml up"

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sh", "-c", keployAlias+" --build")
    if username != "" {
        // print all environment variables
        // Run the command as the user who invoked sudo to preserve the user environment variables and PATH
        cmd = exec.CommandContext(ctx, "sudo", "-E", "-u", os.Getenv("SUDO_USER"), "env", "PATH="+os.Getenv("PATH"), "sh", "-c", "docker-compose up")
    }

    // Set the cancel function for the command
    cmd.Cancel = func() error {

        return InterruptProcessTree(cmd, cmd.Process.Pid, syscall.SIGTERM)
    }
    // wait after sending the interrupt signal, before sending the kill signal
    cmd.WaitDelay = 3 * time.Second

    cmd.SysProcAttr = &syscall.SysProcAttr{
        Setpgid:   true,
        Pdeathsig: syscall.SIGTERM,
    }

    // Set the output of the command
    cmd.Stdout = os.Stdout
    cmd.Stderr = os.Stderr

    err := cmd.Start()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("errro", err.Error())
    }
    fmt.Println("the pid", cmd.Process.Pid)
    go func() {
        time.Sleep(10 * time.Second)
        fmt.Println("the chils pids" + fmt.Sprint(FindChildPIDs(cmd.Process.Pid)))
    }()
    err = cmd.Wait()
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("errro")
    }
}
```

The problem that I face is:[Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8s95T.png)

I've to send cancel signal again to close it, even when I do so the process takes time to stop.

Is there any way to end the process then only move ahead?

Meaning once a pid is successfully killed then only I proceed to kill other PID, I tried using process but nothing worked.

```
for _, pid := range children {
        fmt.Println("this is child pid", pid)
        if cmd.ProcessState == nil {
            err := syscall.Kill(pid, sig)
            if err != nil {
                fmt.Println("failed to send signal to process", zap.Int("pid", pid), zap.Error(err))
            }
            // time.Sleep(250 * time.Millisecond)
        }
    }
```

I'm not inclined on using time.sleep.
The other problem I face is the log "this is child pid" never appears.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to properly let goroutine finish gracefully when main is interrupted?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78087167/how-to-properly-let-goroutine-finish-gracefully-when-main-is-interrupted)

Comment: Please use the search. This question has in one form or the other be answered. You are doing it way too complicated. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78087167/how-to-properly-let-goroutine-finish-gracefully-when-main-is-interrupted/78090320#78090320 for example.

Comment: Hey @MarkusWMahlberg I tried to recreate this as an isolate example, I'm contributing to an open source project when has similar implementation.
https://github.com/keploy/keploy/pull/1708

Basically the go binary would start a docker image which would start the docker image of source project.

The problem I am facing there is while terminating the child processes, if delay is added containers are stopped, if not containers keep running.

Comment: This sounds an awful lot like reimplementing the wheel, or in this case an orchestration for docker containers. There are plenty of well tested, tried and true options available. Also, you are aware that it is a rather bad idea to call a binary when you can as well communicate via `docker.sock`? That being said - the way to stop is the same: create a context listening to signals. If a docker container is stopped, first the TERM and then the KILL signal is sent.

Comment: @MarkusWMahlberg The reason binary needs to be run is the docker- image needs certain params for linux,colima and etc thus to ease it up for users the org implemented it in a way binary runs the docker image. the info you gave about is the one implemented, but that's where problem occurs, the child process are stopped singal is recieved yet containers aren't stopped. Thus created an isolated example as to replicate instead of running the entire code base.

Comment: Since you have the PID and seem to be working on linux shell only from your exec commands you could use another command exec -> bash sudo kill <PID>... it wouldn't be a golang solution but it works quite well i guess :)

Comment: @ShivamJha And that is something which cannot be done with the [Go docker client](https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/docker/docker/client)?