How works process termination and signal interception in Go + cobra?
Here is the compressed code that everything hints at deleting the temporary folder after the process is finished, like ctrl+c or ctrl+z in xfce terminal.
package main

import (
    "context"
    "os"
    "sync"
    "os/signal"
    "path/filepath"
    "syscall"

    "github.com/spf13/cobra"
)

var testCmd = &cobra.Command{
    Use:   "test-app",
    Short: "",
    Run: func(cmd *cobra.Command, args []string) {
        stop := make(chan struct{})
        _, cancel := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
        defer cancel()
        var wg sync.WaitGroup
        wg.Add(2)

        go func() {
            defer wg.Done()
            tmpDir := filepath.Join(".", "tmp")
            os.MkdirAll(tmpDir, os.ModePerm);
     
            // ... some work in tmpDir

            defer func() {
                if err := os.Chdir(".."); err != nil {
                    os.RemoveAll(tmpDir);
                }
            }()

            handleSignals(stop, cancel)
        }()
        wg.Wait()
    },
}

func handleSignals(stop chan struct{}, cancel context.CancelFunc) {
    signalChan := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
    signal.Notify(signalChan, syscall.SIGINT, syscall.SIGTERM, syscall.SIGTSTP)

    go func() {
        <-signalChan
        cancel()
        close(stop)
    }()
    defer func() {
        if err := os.Chdir(".."); err != nil {
            tmpDir := filepath.Join(".", "tmp")
            os.RemoveAll(tmpDir);
        }
    }()
}

func main() {
    if err := testCmd.Execute(); err != nil {
        os.Exit(1)
    }
}

And it doesn't always work, probably depending on the conditions of the process from which the termination signal comes. I can't figure out why this is the case, even after logging on every line.
Here's what I tried  Exiting go applications gracefully
and https://stackoverflow.com/a/78090320/16663300
I'm more interested in why this in theory might work differently in different terminals and how it works internally. How to correctly use several ways of termination handling for different cases? But unfortunately the documentation didn't help https://pkg.go.dev/os/signal because of using multiple termination handling and low experience in Go.
upd: After double-checking the example, I realized that without working inside the tmp folder, the program behaves differently, which is now harder to understand.
upd1: The program on different systems may work correctly, or fail to delete a folder, or freeze during termination. For example windows terminal and xfce. I need to debug this for emergency crashes and understand.

Your code doesn't compile: ./main.go:19:3: ctx declared and not used ./main.go:54:17: undefined: tmpDir.

Signals are correctly caught and handled it the goroutine in
handleSignals(), what makes you think they aren't?

Is your problem that os.RemoveAll(tmpDir) part isn't called when SIGINT, SIGTERM or SIGTSTP is received?

@arkadiusz-drabczyk , no, if I remove defer func() in handling it still doesn't work

do you want your program to exit immediately after receiving the signal?

No, I need to process it correctly and some operations to finalize it
